# Is Android FAT / FAT32 implementation power failure resilient?

Tags: file-system, kernel

Does the android FAT/32 implementation handle sudden battery removal?

I know that Symbian's 'Rugged FAT' (efat32.fsy) and Microsoft's T-Fat implement this, but I've not been able to find any information regarding Android.

Answer (score 2):

Fat32 in Android usually only applies to the External SD card, no longer supported by Google. AFAIK it was a fairly generic implementation as it was only for the card.

Since most of the newer devices use eMMC,the file system android uses is **ext4** except for firmware, which is **vFat**. Example below is from a Galaxy S4

- /system **ext4**
- /data **ext4**
- /cache **ext4**
- /firmware **vfat**

In terms of a little detail on the Android File System:

From [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421826/what-is-androids-file-system)

It depends on what filesystem, for example /system and /data are yaffs2 while /sdcard is vfat. This is the output of mount:

```
rootfs / rootfs ro 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw 0 0
tmpfs /sqlite_stmt_journals tmpfs rw,size=4096k 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock0 /system yaffs2 ro 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock1 /data yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/block/mtdblock2 /cache yaffs2 rw,nosuid,nodev 0 0
/dev/block//vold/179:0 /sdcard vfat rw,dirsync,nosuid,nodev,noexec,uid=1000,gid=1015,fmask=0702,dmask=0702,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro 0 0
```